# Call F# function from C# passing function as a parameter

Tags: c#, f#

I have the following F# function

```
let Fetch logger id = 
    logger "string1" "string2"
    // search a database with the id and return a result
```

In my C# class I want to call the *Fetch* F# function mocking out the *logger* function.
So I have the following C# function as the mocker.

```
void Print(string x, string y) { // do nothing }
```

I'm trying to call the F# function from a C# class with the following.

```
var _logger = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<string, string>(Print);
var _result = Fetch(logger, 3);
```

The problem with FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc is that takes only one type argument.
When I change the *Fetch* F# logger function to the following it works fine when I use ToFSharpFunc(Print) where the C# Print function also takes in one string.

```
let Fetch logger id = 
    logger "string1"
    // search a database with the id and return a result
```

Anyone got ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Version**

```
var tupleLogger = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<Tuple<string,string>>(t=>Print(t.Item1,t.Item2));
var logger = FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled(tupleLogger);

MyOtheProject.MyModule.Fetch(logger, 3);
```

**Long Version**

F# functions only accept one argument. Multiple arguments essentially create nested functions. You need to do the same on C#'s side.

Check the type of the `logger` parameter in C# with Intellisense. It's

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<string, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc<string, a>>
```

[FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/funcconvert.tofsharpfunc%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) can't create this. [FuncFromTupled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/funcconvert.funcfromtupled%5b%27t1%2c%27t2%2c%27u%5d-method-%5bfsharp%5d) though can create this from an FSharpFunc that takes a *Tuple* with multiple fields as an argument.

That's something that *can* be created by ToFsharpFunc :

```
FSharpFunc<Tuple<string,string>,Unit> tupleLogger = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<Tuple<string,string>>(
       t=> Print(t.Item1,t.Item2));
```

or

```
var tupleLogger = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<Tuple<string,string>>(t=> Print(t.Item1,t.Item2));
```

As `FuncFromTupled`'s description says, it's `A utility function to convert function values from tupled to curried form.`. `tupleLogger` is a tupled form that we need to convert to a curried form:

```
var logger = FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled(tupleLogger);
```

The resulting code looks like:

```
var tupleLogger = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<Tuple<string,string>>(t=>Print(t.Item1,t.Item2));
var logger = FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled(tupleLogger);

MyOtheProject.MyModule.Fetch(logger, 3);
```

You could create a utility function to combine the two conversions :

```
public static class MyFuncConvert
{
    public static FSharpFunc<T1, FSharpFunc<T2, Unit>> ToFSharpFunc<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action)
    {
        var tupled = FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<Tuple<T1, T2>>(
                                  t => action(t.Item1, t.Item2));
        var curried = FuncConvert.FuncFromTupled(tupled);
        return curried;
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to write :

```
var logger = MyFuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<string,string>(Print);
```

Answer (score 4):

F# functions can have only one argument. When you have for example: `logger "string1" "string2"` the expression `logger "string1"` creates another function with `"string1"` inside it which then can take `"string2"` as an argument. So to convert this you can create such helper method:

```
public static class FuncConvertExt
{
    public static FSharpFunc<T1, FSharpFunc<T2, Unit>> Create<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action)
    {
        Converter<T1, FSharpFunc<T2, Unit>> conv = value1 =>
        {
            return FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<T2>(value2 => action(value1, value2));
        };

        return FSharpFunc<T1, FSharpFunc<T2, Unit>>.FromConverter(conv);
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
var func = FuncConvertExt.Create<string, string>(Print);
func.Invoke("aaa").Invoke("bbb");
```

More info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2010/07/27/converting-system-funct1-tn-to-fsharpfuncttresult/